# How to properly use multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, eof, pyside6

I am trying to run a long function by pushing a button without making the main screen freeze, I was using thread and it was working fine, but now I need to add a cancel button and kill that thread, one way was to use multiprocessing instead of threading, but when I tried to use it, it gave me this error: `EOFError: Ran out of input`. Here's my code ...

```
def process_(self):
    self.pr = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.main)
    self.pr.start()

def cancel_(self):
    self.pr.terminate()
    self.view.Pages.setCurrentIndex(0)

def main(self):
    while True:
        print("asd")
```

Comment: The RIGHT way to do this is to add code in your thread to check a "terminate" flag periodically, to allow it to commit suicide cleanly.

Comment: Using multiprocessing for that is probably the worst solution. Do you understand the difference between multiprocessing and multithreading? Depending on the situation, stopping a thread might be as easy as setting a boolean variable, so, please [edit] your post and provide more details about the "long function", possibly with a [mre]. Besides, UI elements can only be accessed from the main thread (which automatically means that they cannot be accessed from external processes for obvious reasons).

Comment: Yeah, you're going about it the wrong way. Look into using `requestInterruption()` and `isInterruptionRequested()`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html

Comment: I've got some multiprocessing examples built in Jupyter Notebooks available here. The timer one [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-make-start-and-stop-buttons/8331/4?u=fomightez) is closest to what you describe. [This one](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/running-a-cell-in-a-background-thread/12267/3) is simpler. Maybe one will provide some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @GordonAitchJay QThread is working now